# how can i save my map permanently?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey everyone ,
hope you are all fine .
After 2 months of working on our turtlebot to build our map using [GMapping](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM)
we finally today were able to build our map successfully and were able to navigate on it using [Autonomous navigation](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map)
but we are afraid to turn off our laptops O.o
we are afraid that the map disappear by shutting down the operating system (because it happens every time :( )so is there any way to save the map permanently.
please need help :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62130/how-can-i-save-my-map-permanently-?/) by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosrun map_server map_saver -f save_map_file`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-05-06**:
u mean to change the  command from:-
"rosrun map_server map_saver -f /tmp/my_map"
to this one ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-05-06**:
It's the same command, just another filename to save to.

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-05-06**:
ops!!!...i am sorry to ask such naive question :( .. it was such a lack of concentration .. thanks very much ^_^